# Eclipse Spring boot can't connect tomcat7 server

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Im trying to run an Spring boot application. When I run the application I got this output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.HelloApplication.main(HelloApplication.java:10)
```

After this, I installed tomcat7 and it's working. But when I try to connect eclipse to my tomcat i got this message from eclipse: `Access denied`.

```
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config.
```

Comment: You need to properly configure the tomcat config at the indicated location.